# Android sqlite idimage can not be null

Tags: android, sql, database, null

I have a problems when i want to add something in my DB. I get error 19 idimage can not be null, i do not understand why i get this error, i defined that idimage is auto increment.

Thanks for your help

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;

public class BaseSqlLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


private static final String CREATE_BDD =
    "CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t_image` (`idimage` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMET,`name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,`description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,`rank` TINYINT NOT NULL ,`date` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,PRIMARY KEY (`idimage`) )";

public BaseSqlLite(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_BDD);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE  t_image ;");
    onCreate(db);
}
}


        ImagesBDD imagesBdd = new ImagesBDD(context);


        SimpleDateFormat timeStampFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss");

        String PhotoName = "photo_" + timeStampFormat.format(new Date()) +".jpg" ;
        String descri = myInputText.getText().toString();
        int rank = 1;
        String date = timeStampFormat.format(new Date());

        Image image = new Image(PhotoName,descri,rank,date);


        // Open the BD
        imagesBdd.open();
        // insert of the image
        imagesBdd.insertImage(image);
```

Hello, thanks for your answer i still have the problems.

There is more information.

I changed my sql request:

```
        "CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t_image (idimage INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMET,name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,description VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,rank TINYINT NOT NULL ,date VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL )";
```

There is the logcat error:

```
 E/SQLiteDatabase(19708): Error inserting rank=1 date=2013-04-25-15.53.20 description=gun name=photo_2013-04-25-15.53.20.jpg
E/SQLiteDatabase(19708): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: t_image.idimage may not be NULL (code 19)
```

There is the code for the insertion:

```
 // Insetion d'imahe
public long insertImage(Image image){
    //Création d'un ContentValues 
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    //on lui ajoute une valeur associé à une clé (qui est le nom de la colonne dans laquelle on veut mettre la valeur)
    values.put(COL_NAME, image.getName());
    values.put(COL_DESCRIPTION, image.getDescription());
    values.put(COL_RANK, image.getRank());
    values.put(COL_DATE, image.getDate());
    //on insère l'objet dans la BDD via le ContentValues
    return bdd.insert(TABLE_ImageS, null, values);
}
```

Comment: post the code that insert the data and complete stack trace from logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think error is in your syntax.

```
private static final String CREATE_BDD =
    " CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t_image` (`idimage` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMET,`name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,`description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,`rank` TINYINT NOT NULL ,`date` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,PRIMARY KEY (`idimage`) )";
```

this should be

```
private static final String CREATE_BDD =
    "CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t_image (idimage INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMET,name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,description VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,rank TINYINT NOT NULL ,date VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,PRIMARY KEY (idimage) )";
```

Quets will not come for table name and column names.

Just try it.

I hope this will help you.